# How do I copy JavaDocs to another location

Tags: gradle

In order to build my JavaDocs I do:

```
gradle javadoc
```

Gradle puts them in `build/docs/javadoc`.  I'd like to either generate them to `manual/javadoc` or copy them there along with the `gradle javadoc` process.  How can I do that?

Thanks for the help!

Blake

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc:destinationDir

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)!  With your pointer I was able to come up with the following solution:

```
javadoc {
    destinationDir = new File('manual/javadoc')
}
```

Comment: It's advisable to put generated content under `$buildDir` so that it gets cleaned via `gradle clean`. Putting it here also has the added bonus that no one will try and commit it to source control as the build dir is typically ignored (ie for git it's blacklisted in `.gitignore`)